# Invoke HTTP error : certification path to requested target

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a cluster managed with cloudera, I have installed CFM (Nifi) with the tutorial; also secured the nifi nodes with TLS/SSL.
When I tried the invokeHTTP processor, I have the following  bulletin:

> InvokeHTTP[id=3c2dea7a-0172-1000-0000-0000350072f1] Yielding processor due to exception encountered as a source processor: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I have tried with and without a secured cluster (with the help of Nifi CA toolkit service), without any success.
I also tried to create a controller service to force path of the trustore and keystore.

Now I am clueless on what to do, any ideas?

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@pdeuxa you need to configure the SSLContextService for the resource you are connecting to not the nifi cluster.   You do this by adding the resource's SSL Certificates to a local nifi truststore, then tell NiFi where the truststore is.   The files need to be properly owned for nifi and copied to all nifi nodes.

Comment: Steven, thank  you for your answer; I will try what you are proposing. I previously used Nifi in a docker environement, and http requests work without configuring any additionnal service. I do not really understand why I have do to so with a cloudera cluster, moreover for a public http address.

Comment: The public HTTP(S) address is presenting a certificate, and your processor did not have any known good certificates to verify that against. By giving it access to the Java `cacerts` (a default collection of known good certificates), it can check the presented cert against that list and verify it.

Answer (score 1):

It works with SSLcontext configuration!

I copied the cacert from java jdk on each nifi nodes, and grant ownership to the cacert to nifi user.

On the SSL context configuration I added the path of the copied cacert for keystore and trustore (the defaut password for java cacert is "changeit").

Then I forced invokehttp "proxy type" property on "http"